# Does Bohr's solution to Einstein's Light-box experiment work without gravity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, quantum-interpretations, thought-experiment, unified-theories

[PS: Not a science student beyond high school]

Hi,
I was reading a book on the debates surrounding interpretations of quantum mechanics ([link)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002RI9ZRC) and it discussed how the solution to Einstein's Light-box experiment was solved by Bohr by relying on the uncertainty of measuring time in a gravitational field.

1. What if the light-box is put in a rocketship? That way it's only an accelerated frame of reference, that way the gravitational time dilation wouldn't take place
2. Doesn't this solution to the thought experiment indirectly assume a unified field theory?

The book says that upon Bohr's death the last thing on his blackboard was him trying to work out another solution to the light-box, which makes me wonder if he also wasn't satisfied with his solution.

EDIT:
I wrote this question under the assumption that the time dilation is uniform across the length of a rocketship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we placed the thought experiment in an accelerated frame of reference we would obtain the same result. So putting the box in a rocket ship does not change Bohr’s argument. This is a consequence of the [equivalence principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle), which simply states that gravitational acceleration due to a massive body is indistinguishable from acceleration.

Comment: Ah, I thought the equivalence principle only applied to classical properties such as momentum etc *and that time dilation is non-uniform only in a gravitational field. I didn't realize that time dilation is not uniform even inside a rocketship.

(edited my reply for clarity)